# What are these strange icons in 'My Computer'?

Tags: windows-7

I am getting these strange drivers on my computer. I unplugged all portable hard drives but  for some reason I am getting these strange icons. Please could someone tell me what they are and how to remove them if that is possible. If it helps each drive has zero data.

[image]

Comment: Windows 7 calls it "Computer", not "My Computer" (a great improvement IMHO).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have some memory card readers (or a multi-format card reader) installed on your computer. They show up as drives.

Comment: @Alexander: Please remember to mark the correct answer as the solution to your question. Thanks :)